# Resolve multiple namespace

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

How would I get the XElement for the "HR" and "Cad" nodes in the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="StravaGPX" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
   <metadata>
      <time>2011-07-16T13:39:22Z</time>
   </metadata>
   <trk>
      <name>07/16/2011 Toronto, ON, Canada</name>
      <trkseg>
         <trkpt lat="43.7076220" lon="-79.3164530">
            <ele>138.4</ele>
            <time>2011-07-16T13:39:22Z</time>
            <extensions>
               <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
                  <gpxtpx:hr>124</gpxtpx:hr>
                  <gpxtpx:cad>90</gpxtpx:cad>
               </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
            </extensions>
         </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
   </trk>
</gpx>
```

I can resolve the  element with the following code:

```
loaded.Descendants("{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}trkpt") // Where 'loaded' is the XDocument
```

but when I look at the  element in the debugger it only shows me the `<ele>` and `<time>` elements and ignores the `<TrackPointExtension>` and `<extension>` elements that are descendants.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very clear how you used debugger to check, but as far as I can see there should be no descendant of selected node ignored by debugger.

To select an element from XML having multiple namespace prefixes, you just need to use right `XNamespace` prefix for right element, for example :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1";
XNamespace gpx = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1";
var trackPointExt = doc.Root
                       .Element(ns+"trk")
                       .Element(ns+"trkseg")
                       .Element(ns+"trkpt")
                       .Element(ns+"extensions")
                       .Element(gpx+"TrackPointExtension");
var hr = (int)trackPointExt.Element(gpx+"hr");
var cad = (int)trackPointExt.Element(gpx+"cad");
Console.WriteLine(hr);
Console.WriteLine(cad);
```

Comment: Thx har07 that worked.  I had been using Linq stmts to get at the elements and for whatever reason it wasn't picking up the nested elements.  When I reworked the code the way you've laid it out things worked perfectly.